# Git configuration - still ask username and password

Tags: macos, git, github, osx-lion

I'm trying to set pu my git, but I have a little problem with that.

I use Mac OS X Lion and when I go to:

```
~/.ssh/
```

I can see 2 files: id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. I want to generate new SSH key to log in to bitbucket.org for example or github.com. I do:

```
rm ~/.ssh/*
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "example@gmail.com"
```

Then I'm not sure, but I write my mail passphrase, my bitbucket password... everything and I have still this same problem.
When I use:

```
git clone https://...
git pull
```

or something like that it still wants my username and password. Of course I paste new id_rsa.pub key to SSH keys on the website (bitbucket and github). Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're cloning over HTTPS, which doesn't have anything to do with your SSH keys.  Either try cloning using the SSH URL, or you can do passwordless login with HTTPS by the following:

- [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5343068/223092)

Answer (score 0):

You use `https://`, ssh keys are of little help there. Try ssh repository url.